# How can I wait the generation of the map to do some actions?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm working with a map activity in android studio.
I need to wait that the locationListener get the first position of the user to start a function. How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wait for onMapReady callback , and you can know that your map not null :

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
   //your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a callback for the `OnMapLoaded` event:

```
...
    private var map: GoogleMap? = null
...
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState?.getBundle(MAP_VIEW_BUNDLE_KEY)
    mapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle)
    ...
    mapView.getMapAsync {
        map = it
    }

    map?.setOnMapLoadedCallback {
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Loaded...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        map?.snapshot(callback) // OK to take snapshot after load
    }
}
```